# Is it possible to redeem a Google promo code in a Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have created an app that is listed for free in the Google Play Store and Apple Store, with in-app subscriptions. Part of my marketing strategy is to offer certain people free subscriptions—which I can do easily in the Apple App Store, but cannot seem to figure out for Google Play.

Does anyone have insight into this? I've read some threads about in-app redemption flows for promo codes, but there is no structure for that. I pulled this from another question:

What I've tried so far:

**Promo codes for SUBSCRIPTION**: They only give a longer free trial (and charge user afterwards if they don't cancel). The Promo codes worked fine but this is not really suitable for us because it can charge users.

**Promo codes for PRODUCT:** A friend suggested to create an in-app Product that unlocks premium content and promo code would give this product for free. I've generated promo codes for it and started testing it through Internal testing. The Google Play documentation says it's possible to Redeem the code from A) Google Play or B) from your app.

**Problems with both options:**

A) Google play: When we Redeem the code from Google Play, the code is accepted and message is displayed saying the product was applied. However: we don't get any purchase notification in our backend system (there was no received message in play_billing Pub sub topic where we usually receive purchase notifications from Google Play).

The purchase is also not visible in Google Play Developer Console > Orders.
When we try to buy the product from the app (for same Google account) we get Google in-app purchase dialog with Error: You already own this item. We tried clearing Google play app's cache and data but that didn't help.

there is no method in Flutter in-app-purchase plugin that we can use to query if user has already purchased the product (and just unlock the premium content then),

B) From the app: I don't think this is supported by official Flutter in-app-purchase plugin. The plugin documentation only mentions Apple store Promo codes. Also when we press the button to buy the product the Google in-app purchase dialog doesn't contain any option to use Promo code. And no, I didn't use Licence testing (test card) but my real private credit card.

I feel so stuck!!! Any help is much appreciated!